# Matrix differentiation by a vector in Least Squares method

Tags: calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

In a book *The Elements of
Statistical Learning* published by Springer we can find following statement:

> We can write
>
> $RSS(\beta) = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$
>
> where $\mathbf{X}$ is an $N\times p$ matrix with each row an input vector, and $\mathbf{y}$ is an $N$-vector of the outputs in the training set. Differentiating w.r.t. $\beta$ we get the *normal equations*
>
> $\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = 0$

#### Questions

How do I formally derive the *normal equations* operating on matrix level calculations without diving into operating on scalar elements?

Is my **Second attemp** valid?

#### First attemp

Note: $\beta$ is an $p$-vector. Let us assume that vectors are vertical matrixes.

As in *The Matrix Cookbook* (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf) let us assume that
$\partial\mathbf{X}^T = (\partial\mathbf{X})^T$
and
$\partial(\mathbf{XY})=\partial(\mathbf{X})\mathbf{Y}+\mathbf{X}\partial(\mathbf{Y})$.

Let us differentiate with respect to $\beta$ and observe that $\partial (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)=-\mathbf{X}$.

Now $\partial RSS(\beta)=(\partial (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)+(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^T  \partial (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$

Which gives us $\partial RSS(\beta)=-\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)-(\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))^T$

At this point we find contradiction because dimensions are incompatible to perform summation. $\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$ is vertical $p$-vector, while $(\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta))^T$ is horizontal $p$-vector.

#### Second attemp

If I assumed $\partial(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y})=\partial(\mathbf{X})^T\mathbf{Y}+(\mathbf{X}^T\partial(\mathbf{Y}))^T$

I would get that
$\partial RSS(\beta)=-2\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$, which matches with the *normal equations* from the book.

Comment: there must be a lot of examples to show the derivative of $\|Y - X\beta\|^2$ with respect to  $\beta$... not index notation

Comment: The problem with your first attempt is that the product rule $$d(XY)=dX\,Y+X\,dY$$ applies, **not** to gradients, but to differentials (and to time derivatives). In your second attempt, the presumed rule only holds when $(X,Y)$ are vectors -- which, fortunately, they are. So there are problems with both approaches, but the 2nd is less problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not found an example, then here it goes.

---

Before we start deriving the gradient, some facts and notations for brevity:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= B^T A :  C  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f := \left\|y- X\beta \right\|^2 = \left(y- X\beta \right)^T \left(y- X\beta \right) = y- X\beta:y- X\beta$.

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
df  
&= d\left( y- X\beta:y- X\beta \right) \\
&= 2\left(y- X\beta \right) : -X d\beta \\
&= -2X^T\left(y- X\beta\right) : d\beta\\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \left( \left\|y - X \beta \right\|^2 \right)=  -2X^T\left(y- X\beta\right).
\end{align}